# fullCalendar v2: fixed slotDuration & variable cell height

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

This is regarding [fullCalendar.io](http://fullcalendar.io/)

When in the week view, I want to increase the height of the rows for the hours.

I expect the height of the calendar & all the event added to scale/adjust automatically.

I expected some hook in the library in order to do that, but I cannot find anything that does the job. I looked into the options `aspectRatio`, `contentHeight`, and `height` but none of them seem to do what I am looking for.

Typically, when changing `contentHeight` to a new value at calendar's initialization, the rows for the hours stay the same height. And a big empty row is added underneath the last hour (see screenshot below)

[image: fullCalendar scaling going wrong]

On the other hand, changing `aspectRatio` does not seem to have any effect at all. Even after removing `height` and `contentHeight` from the set options. I may be missing something here.

Finally, I decided to look into a CSS solution. It seems like using a selector to force the rows to a specific height works. Not sure if that's the right way to go though, as the styling of events (& maybe more?) may go wrong as a side effect. This is by doing something like:

```
 .fc-slats tr { height: 50px !important; }
```

#### Resources

- http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/aspectRatio/
- http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/contentHeight/
- http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/height/